# Enviiar variable mediante formulario html a php

Tags: php, formularios

El problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto este formulario desde una pagina externa, el input de nombre token, no se pasa. La pagina confirmar.php abre pero no se ejecuta el echo que tengo en ella.  He de decir que es un formulario que creo en php y mando por email. Si genero un formulario desde una pagina del mismo servidor si aparece el texto del echo.
Decir que la pagina desde fuera abre y se pongo un texto a pelo, el texto aparece. El problema es que no se pasa el input token. ¿Podría ser un problema con el certificado del dominio?
Por si vale de algo, al ejecutar el submit del form, sale un mensaje diciendo que **vas a enviar informacion a una pagina externa, quieres continuar.**

En la pagina cofirmar tengo:

```
$token= $_POST['token'];
echo $token;
```

Y la pagina desde donde llamo.

```
$cuerpo = '<form action="http://privada.mgsehijos.es/preproduccion/php/confirmar.php"   method="post">'.
            '<input type="text"  name="token" value="prueba"><br>'.
            ' <input type="submit" value="Enlace">'.
            '</form>';
             mail($para,$de,$cuerpo,$headers);
```

Comment: Me parece que estas confundido.  El input token no debe de aparecer en la URL porque lo estas enviando por el metodo POST.  Ademas las formas dentro de un email no siempre funcionan.  Mira este link: https://www.sitepoint.com/forms-in-email/

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y el enlace, Conoces alguna forma de hacerlo? Necesito validar una cuenta de correo y para eso tengo que pasar una variable desde el correo que mando.

Comment: El problema es con el certificado que tiene algún tipo de error, poniendo mi ordenador como servidor si pasa bien la variable. De paso me he informado un poco sobre get y post. Gracias  @alanfcm

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que la página donde se encuentra confirmar.php esté en https y no http?

Comment: Maravilloso, el problema es que el enlace era http y la pagina https, por eso no salia. Muchisimas gracias